# Saving node's fields without saving the node itself drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

```
//i would like to use a Drupal function named field_attach_update() for certain nodeids
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->field_fieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'some value';
field_attach_update('node', $node);
```

I need to create a function, and place it in drupal folder, and run it for thousands of nodes. I have the node ids i want to change their subfields value.

How the above code should be altered so as to change only the subfields value, and give as parameter all nodes that i need the change to be done?

I would like to use drush to run the function

And for sure something like is not a good solution...(perhaps i should add some timer between each save? i need to update 20k nodes, and not crash our server that hosts drupal)

```
$node = node_load(123);
    $node->field_fieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'some value';
    field_attach_update('node', $node);
$node = node_load(124);
    $node->field_fieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'some value';
    field_attach_update('node', $node);
```

...

Comment: You may want to use the [batch api](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/batch-api/overview) or maybe create a function that leverages the [views bulk operations module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). Voting to close this though as there are many ways this could be done and would result in opinion based answers. Also, I am not sure why the title says "without saving the node itself" as you will need to save the node if you change the field value (unless you do it directly via the database)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, BatchApi will be the better solution for this. I prefer VBO only under 1k nodes for bulk updates.
Here is a helpful post for Batch on a custom drush command:

https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-batch-api